# How to override Jest mock in setupTests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I added `jest.mock('./Component')` in `setupTests.js` because I don't want to do it in every test that has `Component`.

But now, when I want to test `Component`, it is mocked.

How can I override or reset it, in order to have the original `Component`?

I have tried so far:

- jest.unmock(moduleName)
- jest.dontMock(moduleName)
- jest.clearAllMocks()
- jest.resetAllMocks()
- jest.restoreAllMocks()
- jest.resetModules()

and:

```
jest.mock('./index', () => ({
  Component: 'Component'
}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`jest.unmock(moduleName)`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestunmockmodulename) should make the work but only when it's used **before test's `describe` block**.

Jest transpiles your tests in its very own way in order to make all the mocking/unmocking magic happen.